# Gathering heterogeneous data with hadoop

Tags: hadoop

We have a system, including some Oracle and Microsoft SQL DBMS, that get data from some different sources and in different formats, stores and process it. "Different formats" means files: dbf, xls and others, including binary formats (images), which are imported to DBMS with different tools, and direct access to the databases. I want to isolate all the incoming data and store it "forever" and want to get them later by source and creation time. After some studies I want to try hadoop ecosystem, but not quite sure, if it's an adequate solution for this goal. And what parts of ecosystem should I use? HDFS alone, Hive, may be something else? Could you give me a piece of advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to store the files that contain the data -- effectively a searchable file archive.

The files themselves can just be stored in HDFS ... or you may find a system like Amazon's S3 cheaper and more flexible.  As you store the files, you could manage the other data about the data, namely: location, source, and creation time by appending to another file -- a simple tab-separated file or several other formats supported by Hadoop make this easy.

You can manage and query the file with Hive or other SQL-on-Hadoop tools.  In effect, you're creating a simple file system with special attributes, so the trick would be to make sure that each time you write a file, you also write the metadata.  You may have to handle cases like write failures, what happens when you delete, rename, or move files (I know, you say "never").

Your solution might be simpler depending on your needs, you may find that storing the data in subdirectories within HDFS (or AWS S3) is even simpler.  Perhaps if you wanted to store DBF files from source "foo", and XLS files from "bar" created on December 1, 2015, you could simply create a directory structure like

```
/2015/12/01/foo/dbf/myfile.dbf
/2015/12/01/bar/xls/myexcel.xls
```

This solution has the advantage of being self-maintaining -- the file path stores the metadata which makes it very portable and simple, requiring nothing more than a shell script to implement.

I don't think there's any reason to make the solution more complicated than necessary.  Hadoop or S3 are both fine for long-term, high-durability storage and for querying.  My company has found that storing the information about the file in Hadoop (which we use for many other purposes) and storing the files themselves on AWS S3 is far simpler, more easily secured and much cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to organize simple file storage because it's just a first step - after that I want to add some  possibilities for data analisys. The problem is that I can't say for now, what exactly is in all of this files ) I can say about the part of them, but the whole system is pretty old, complicated and full of legacy code. There is no single person who knows all the data sources for it (or even all the components of this system). So one purpose is to account all the incoming data and systemize it.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things that you may want to do, each with their own solution. If more than 1 use case is relevant for you, you probably want to implement multiple solutions in parallel.

## 1. Store files for use

If you want to store files in a way that they can be picked up efficiently (distributed), the solution is simple: **Put the files on hdfs**

## 2. Store the information for use

If you want to use the information, rather than storing the files you should be interested in storing the information in a way that they can be picked up efficiently. The general solution here would be: **Parse the files in a lossles way and store their information in a database**

You may find that storing information in (partitioned) ORC files can be nice for this. You can do this with Pive, Pig or even UDFs (e.g. python) in Pig.

## 3. Keep the files for the future

In this case you would mostly care about preserving the files, and not so much about ease of access. Here the recommended solution is: **Store compressed files with proper backups**

Note that the replication that hdfs does is to deal more efficiently with data (and hardware issues). Just having your data on hdfs does NOT mean that it is backed up.

Comment: The first two cases are relevant. I plan to start from the first approach, and than move to the second, where it would be possible (for example, part of the incoming data are images of scanned documents).